# Código do Analytics aparecendo na Home Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-analytics-api

Por algum motivo o código do Google Analytics está aparecendo na home page de uma cliente minha e não estou conseguindo remove-lo de la. E ao mesmo tempo, obviamente, preciso que ele continue funcionando.

[image: Aqui estão as opções que foram usada para o código:]

O código ficou assim:`onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Forms', 'Click');"`

Ele foi inserido no final do editor de HTML que tem dentro do CMS. Todo o conteúdo abaixo fica dentro da tag BODY. E ficou assim:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://d335luupugsy2.cloudfront.net/js/loader-scripts/2c4203a9-ed9e-4af1-94f8-d40cb871826f-loader.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d335luupugsy2.cloudfront.net/js/integration/stable/rd-js-integration.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function sendContactToRD(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = jQuery(event.target).closest('form');
  var data_array = form.find(':input').serializeArray();
  data_array.push(
    { name: 'identificador', value: 'Contato' },
    { name: 'token_rdstation', value: '3b186d9de846a1105cb4fe3ef63b8e95' }
  );
  RdIntegration.post(data_array, function(){
    buttonContato.unbind('click', sendContactToRD).click();
    buttonContato.bind('click', sendContactToRD);
    return false;
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
buttonContato = jQuery(':submit');
buttonContato.bind('click', sendContactToRD);
});
</script>

<!-- Google Code for Espa&ccedil;o Exato - Tag de Convers&atilde;o Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 968350051;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "j1WcCImatnIQ47LfzQM";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/968350051/?label=j1WcCImatnIQ47LfzQM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
<!-- Código do Google para tag de remarketing -->
<!--------------------------------------------------
As tags de remarketing não podem ser associadas a informações pessoais de identificação nem inseridas em páginas relacionadas a categorias de confidencialidade. Veja mais informações e instruções sobre como configurar a tag em: http://google.com/ads/remarketingsetup
--------------------------------------------------->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 968350051;
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/968350051/?guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>

onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Forms', 'Click');"
```

E por último, o código aparece ali no canto superior esquerdo da home page dessa forma: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já peço desculpas caso seja uma pergunta besta (não achei solução no Google) ou qualquer outra coisa besta, esse é meu primeiro tópico.
Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Esse código era para ser um atributo em algum elemento HTML. Assim no fim como você colocou ele é interpretado como conteúdo normal. Qual elemento deve ser clicável e registrar o evento no analytics?

Comment: Vou perguntar pra cliente e já te respondo, não fui que desenvolvi e recebi esse job com pouca informação. Então eu posso inserir o código no analytics no HEAD do HTML da home page pra ele funcionar direito?

Comment: Basicamente, esse código não funciona. Se ele não faz falta, remova-o. Mas se for necessário, você tem que seguir as instruções do @bfavaretto.

Comment: vou fazer isso sim @TonyMontana, faz muito sentido a orientação dele. Só vou esperar a cliente me responder qual elemento está associado com com o evento do analytics, enquanto procuro por aqui. Infelizmente tenho pouquíssima experiência com analytics. Pouca leia "praticamente nada".

Comment: @bfavaretto todos os formulários do site devem registrar o evento do analyticis. Essa informação é o suficiente?

Comment: Então, não sei se consigo te ajudar muito. Mas tente alterar as tags `<form>` e incluir isso. Vai ficar mais ou menos assim: `<form onsubmit="ga('send', 'event', 'Forms', 'Submit');">`. Não remova os outros atributos dos forms (action, method etc).